# Fluid Domain Re-scaling

Tags: animation

I have the setting of the fluid perfect but the domain is too small and if i make it bigger then the fluid messes up. How do I change the domain size without it effecting the fluid?

Comment: In what way does it mess up the fluid? Can you provide some screenshots or a bit more of an explanation?

Comment: The Fluid Simulation doesn't do what it did previously, Like my fluid is going down a pipe continuously then when I scale it up there is a lot more clumpy fluid. @Brenticus

Comment: That makes more sense. Check out the answer I just posted, it should solve things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fluid simulation uses a certain number of divisions to determine the resolution of the fluid. The number of divisions is related to the domain size in that 1 division will be 1/Domain Size blender units. Therefore scaling up the domain will make each division larger, so your fluid will be less smooth when you scale up the domain.

To make your fluid smoother, select your domain object and adjust the resolution values in the physics tab in the fluid settings. If you are looking for the exact same resolution as you had before, multiply the current resolution value by the amount you scaled the domain (if you scaled the domain by 2, multiply the resolution by 2, etc.). Blender allows you to do math equations in the input boxes as well so it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Awesome! If it fixes your problem please accept this answer so that the question is solved.